# angularjs directive is not recognized

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, using-directives

I created an angularjs directive and it is not recognized when executed.

```js
app.directive('someDirective', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'AE', 
    replace: 'true', 
    transclude: 'true', 
    scope: {
      info: "="
    }, 
    templateUrl: '../info.html'
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

// info.html
<div>
  <img ng-src="someimage.jpg"/>
</div>
<div ng-transclude></div>


//index.html
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="part in parts">
  <some-directive info="part">
    <div>
      <a href="someurl">click here</a>
     </div>
  </some-directive>
</li>
</ul>
```

maybe it is something with the ng-repeat? 
I have a directive that looks just like it and it works..

Thank you!

answers for some of the questions:
I didn't add all of my app code.. only the parts relevant to the question.
There are other directives in the code that are written similar to this one, 
they are placed in the same file as this one so the path is definitely right. 
All templates are placed in the same directory this directive so again - templateUrl is right.. but for some reason this is the only directive that doesn't show. and there is no error in the console.

when putting a breakpoint in the directive return code it does not stop there.. it's like the directive is not recognized at all.

Comment: Are you sure your templateUrl is set correctly?
Usually the templateUrl is not relative to the directive directory but the app directory

Comment: What error you're getting?

Comment: Can't see your ng-app attribute in your html file, probably that's why

Comment: I didn't add all of my app code.. i have another directive that is set exactly the same way, and the template is placed in the same directory as this directive.. but for some reason this is the only directive that doesn't show. and there is no error in the console.

Comment: first check for ng-repeat="part in parts", is there any data available

Comment: 1) Are you sure it's ok to add `<div>` inside custom directive? How it is supposed to be working?
2) If (1) is not a problem, can you provide code of working directory?

Comment: There is data available in parts. and it is okay to add <div> in a custom directive. when i replace the custom directive with the code in the template url it works.. the problem is that the directive is never reached.

Comment: Please share sample data.

Comment: Did you add the directive source script in you application index?